# How can I create my own imagemagick binary releases?

Tags: imagemagick, binary

I'm looking for a way to build ImageMagick binary distributions for deploying my app. I only need it for Kinux 64-bit (Ubuntu/Debian) and OSX.

Actually building it is fine, but I have no idea how to include delegate libraries:

- png
- jpeg
- gif
- tiff
- webp

Something similar is done with ffmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds

Are there instructions or guidelines as to how to do this?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `apt-get install imagemagick`?

Comment: it's too old and it doesn't support webp

Comment: @jordanm - he wants to build it for Ubuntu/Debian and OSX so apt-get won't do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to build ImageMagick so that it's statically built. For example:

```
cd ImageMagick-6.4.0
./configure --disable-shared --enable-delegate-build
make
```

Doing this will make your version portable and completely independent of any system libraries.

#### Follow up questions

*Q #1*

> If I have webp installed, will this include the library in the installation?

*A #1*

Probably not. It won't include any external dependencies such as webp or ghostscript (gv). There isn't any way to include them either as a function of ImageMagick. You're options are to lean on the package manager and include them as "dependencies" or roll them into a tarball yourself and deploy them as binary blobs.

*Q #2*

> Suppose I have the webp binaries (either I package them or build them
>   from source). How do I tell imagemagick where they are, assuming I
>   build with the --with-webp option?

*A #2*

If they aren't in a standard location, `/lib` for example, and they aren't hardcoded into the executables via `make`/`config` then you can use the environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to specify where libraries are to running apps.

Comment: If I have webp installed, will this include the library in the installation?

Comment: @JonathanOng - see updates.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I have the webp binaries (either I package them or build them from source). How do I tell imagemagick where they are, assuming I build with the --with-webp option?

Comment: @JonathanOng - see updates.